# Azure Blueprint with Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, blueprint

Can we apply Azure Blueprints via Jenkins ?
We currently have Blueprints that are applied via Azure DevOps. We have plans to use Jenkins on Azure, so looking for any tips/recommendations for applying Blueprints via Jenkins.

Is Azure DevOps preferred over Jenkins ? Or other way around ? Any pro's and cons?

Comment: We recommend you use the Azure Devops to connect for the Azure Blueprint. And in the azure devops we do have the extension to help us.https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nepeters.azure-blueprints

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure CLI to create [a new blueprint assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/blueprint/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az_blueprint_assignment_create) from the Jenkins pipelines.
or you can use simple PowerShell script and define required parameters in a separate file like in the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/how-to/manage-assignments-ps)